# Do I need to explicitly Flush when using NHibernate HQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In an `NHibernate` session do we need to invoke `Flush()` before executing an `HQL` statement?

I believe `NHibernate` should be smart enough to Flush whenever is dealing with `HQL.

For example,

```
        using (ISession session)
        {
            var query = session.CreateQuery(
                    $"DELETE FROM Table WHERE id = :id")
                .SetParameter("id", someId);

            session.Flush(); //is this necessary?
            query.ExecuteUpdate();
            session.Clear(); //is this necessary?
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to reading data, if your `FlushMode` setting is `Auto`, which is the default, then NH will endeavour to manage flushing so that the result of queries is consistent with what's currently in the session.

However, when it comes to addition, updates and deletes it's important to be explicit. The following code is the canonical example:

```
 using (ISession session)
 using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
 {
     var query = session.CreateQuery(
         $"DELETE FROM Table WHERE id = :id")
            .SetParameter("id", someId);

     query.ExecuteUpdate();

     transaction.Commit();
 }
```

Committing the transaction takes care of the flush for you while providing database consistency.

I must caveat this answer by saying that I rarely use HQL, so my answer could be missing something that's specifically related to HQL and its behaviour.